# how to solve error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended?

Tags: oracle

I have a oracle statement error with error is `'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'`. I don't know to solve this error. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
select a.branch_key, a.code, a.name, a.parent_key 
       from gn_branch a 
       start with a.parent_key = 24 
       connect by prior a.branch_key = a.parent_key
```

And this is the structure of table gn_branch

This is the structure of table gn_branch

```
CREATE TABLE "MEDALLIONSALES"."GN_BRANCH" ("BRANCH_KEY" NUMBER(18,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
                                           "CODE" VARCHAR2(50), 
                                           "BRANCH_TYPE" NUMBER(18,0), 
                                           "PARENT_KEY" NUMBER(18,0), 
                                           "CONTACT_KEY" NUMBER(18,0), 
                                           "NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
                                           "ENABLED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
                                           "REGION" NUMBER(18,0),
                                           "RECORD_STATUS" VARCHAR2(2),
                                           "RECORD_BRANCH" VARCHAR2(50), 
                                           "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
                                           "CREATED_DATE" DATE, 
                                           "MODIFIED_BY" VARCHAR2(50),
                                           "MODIFIED_DATE" DATE, 
                                           "COA_SEGMENT" VARCHAR2(50),
                                           "ARIA_CODE" VARCHAR2(50), 
                                           "SALES_TEAM" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
                                           "COA_EQUAL_BRANCH" NUMBER(1,0),
                                           "BRANCH_LEVEL" NUMBER(18,0), 
                                           "APPROVED_DATE" DATE, 
                                           "APPROVED_BY" VARCHAR2(50), 
                                           "IS_SYARIAH" NUMBER(1,0), 
                                           "SYARIAH_BRANCH_KEY" NUMBER(18,0),
                                 CONSTRAINT "PK_GN_BRANCH" PRIMARY KEY ("BRANCH_KEY")
```

Comment: Could you post the structure of table gn_branch? and How are you running the query (using what tool?)

Comment: Can you try same query using some other tool, say SqlPlus or Sql developer? Adding some sample data to the question will also help in debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're Syntax is correct. Just missing an Semicolon at the end of the SQL-Statement.
Working Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/107f82/2/0
(the CREATE Table Statement misses an ')' at the end)